# Esp32 not sending any response to hercules

Tags: printf, esp32, putty, uart, espressif-idf

I am using ESP wroom 32 as the controller and I am using UART as the protocol to communicate and the Hercules Emulator.

1. Now I want is when i send "AT+SUID=12345678" from the hercules through UART to ESP32.
   So it should check till "AT+SUID=" and stores the rest "12345678" in a first variable.
2. Same for AT+CHNO=1, check till "AT+CHNO=" and stores the rest "1" in second variable.
3. Now at last i will send "AT+SUID?" then there should be a print of the first stored variable     i.e (12345678) in the hercules.

All the above commands should be in Sequence.

> Eg. In the Hercules what the output should be,
> I will send

```
AT+SUID=12345678
AT+CHNO=1
AT+SUID?
```

> Then it should print the below when I send the `AT+SUID? 12345678`

Below is the code

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/queue.h"
#include "driver/uart.h"
#include "driver/gpio.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_system.h"
#include "soc/uart_reg.h"
#include <ctype.h>

static const char *TAG = "UART_TASK";
static const int RX_BUF_SIZE = 1024;
#define TXD_PIN GPIO_NUM_17
#define RXD_PIN GPIO_NUM_16
#define UART_NUM UART_NUM_2

char suidValue[20];
char chnoValue[10];
volatile bool suidReceived = false;
volatile bool chnoReceived = false;

void sendData(const char *logName, const char *data)
{
    const int len = strlen(data);
    const int txBytes = uart_write_bytes(UART_NUM, data, len);
    ESP_LOGI(logName, "Wrote %d bytes", txBytes);
}

void parseUARTData(char *data, size_t len)
{
    esp_log_level_set(TAG, ESP_LOG_INFO);

    if (len >= 8 && strncmp(data, "AT+SUID=", 8) == 0)
    {
        strncpy(suidValue, data + 8, sizeof(suidValue) - 1);
        suidValue[sizeof(suidValue) - 1] = '\0';
        suidReceived = true;
        chnoReceived = false; // Reset CHNO flag
    }
    else if (len >= 8 && strncmp(data, "AT+CHNO=", 8) == 0)
    {
        strncpy(chnoValue, data + 8, sizeof(chnoValue) - 1);
        chnoValue[sizeof(chnoValue) - 1] = '\0';
        chnoReceived = true;
        suidReceived = false; // Reset SUID flag
    }
}

void uart_task(void *pvParameters)
{
    esp_log_level_set(TAG, ESP_LOG_INFO);
    esp_log_set_vprintf(vprintf);
    char data[RX_BUF_SIZE];

    while (1)
    {
        int len = uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM, (uint8_t *)data, RX_BUF_SIZE, 20 /    portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        if (len < 0)
        {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "UART read error: %s", esp_err_to_name(len));
            continue;
        }
        else if (len > 0)
        {
            data[len] = '\0';
            ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Received: %s", data);
            parseUARTData(data, len);
            if (strcmp(data, "AT+SUID?") == 0)
            {
                if (suidReceived)
                {
                    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "SUID Value: %s", suidValue);
                    sendData(TAG, suidValue);
                }
                else
                {
                    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "SUID not received yet");
                }
            }
        }
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}

void init(void)
{
    const uart_config_t uart_config = {
        .baud_rate = 115200,
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
        .source_clk = UART_SCLK_DEFAULT,
    };

    uart_driver_install(UART_NUM, RX_BUF_SIZE * 2, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
    uart_param_config(UART_NUM, &uart_config);
    uart_set_pin(UART_NUM, TXD_PIN, RXD_PIN, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE);

    gpio_config_t io_conf = {
        .pin_bit_mask = (1ULL << RXD_PIN),
        .mode = GPIO_MODE_INPUT,
        .intr_type = GPIO_INTR_ANYEDGE,
        .pull_up_en = GPIO_PULLUP_ENABLE,
    };
    gpio_config(&io_conf);
    gpio_install_isr_service(0);
}

void app_main(void)
{
    init();
    xTaskCreate(uart_task, "uart_task", 2048, NULL, 10, NULL);

    while (1)
    {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Application is running...");
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```